# Retrieve record id of current record being viewed/edited with smartgrid

Tags: web2py

I am using SQLFORM.smartgrid as the basis for an app I am building as it fits the bill almost perfectly.

I am customizing the views generated by smartgrid and would like to add a bit of a dashboard above the record I am viewing. The dashboard will contain data from records in other tables related to the one I am viewing.

How can I retrieve the ID of the current record being viewed in smartgrid? I tried using request.args to extract the id from the url but args are returned as a list and the id does not always have the same index. Checking the list for an integer seems a bit messy and dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of poking and some questions on usenet it turns out that the record id is always the last arg in a the url thus you can use request.args[-1]